# How to render a graphic inside OverviewMap

Tags: dojo, esri, arcgis-js-api

As stated on the docs of ArcGIS API for JavaScript  : Class OverviewMap

> Property Details   overviewMap. The Map instance displayed in the
>   OverviewMap widget's container. This is a separate Map from the Map
>   referenced by the overview map. (Added at v3.14).

I've updated the api version to 3.14, but the instance of the oMap does not have this overviewMap property. I just want to render some graphics inside the overview map apart of the main map. I want to add graphic layers to it and render graphics. I know it is possible in the flex version but I i've tried everything to make it work on the js api without sucess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. After adding the OverviewMap to your map you can access it like this:

```js
var overviewMapDijit = new OverviewMap({
  map: map,
  visible: true
});
overviewMapDijit.startup();

map.on("load", function(){
  // overviewMapDijit.overviewMap is your desired map 
  console.log( overviewMapDijit.overviewMap );
});
```

You can create and add graphics like you do with the normal map, just use `overviewMapDijit.overviewMap` instead of `map`.

See demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/Rhy3AAq4n214a552X7k1?p=preview

Comment: You saved an entire team <3